# How to change the color and width of lines with par function in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a question about the par function in R.

I want to change the color and/or width of a line in a graph with par function. (I am using par function because the gaps.plot command below does not allow "col" option to be included. The gaps.plot command is used after the synth command).

So, I used the following command. But I noticed that the lines of the BOX are changed rather than the lines of the GRAPHS.

```
synth1<-read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\Research\\R\\synthinR_v4.csv",header=TRUE)
attach(synth1)
library("Synth")

dataprep.out34 <- dataprep(foo = synth1, predictors = c("lncdsales", "md1", "md2","md3", "md4", "md5", "md6", "md7", "md8", "md9", "md10", "md11", "yd1", "yd2", "yd3", "yd4", "yd5", "yd6", "yd7", "yd8"), predictors.op = "mean", time.predictors.prior = -13:1, dependent = "lndigital", unit.variable = "artistalbumcode", time.variable = "release", treatment.identifier = 34, controls.identifier = c(1:33, 35:49), time.optimize.ssr = -13:1, time.plot = -13:25)

synth.out34 <- synth(data.prep.obj = dataprep.out34, method = "BFGS")

par(lwd = 2, col="#cccccc")

gaps.plot(synth.res = synth.out34, dataprep.res = dataprep.out34, Ylab = " Log Digital Sales ", Xlab = "Release", Ylim = c(-7, 7) , Main = NA)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem??
Thank you in advance for your willingness to help. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: From which library did you take `plot.gaps` function? It is not a base graphics...

Comment: flagged for migration to SO, also we don't have `synth1` please make this reproducible by providing the data set from the output of `dput(synth1)` or provide a small today data set

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention!!! Is it possible to attach a csv file on this site?

Comment: The gaps.plot is from library("Synth")

Comment: You could probably change your code to `synth1 <- read.csv(file="https://fs13n2.sendspace.com/dl/ecc7afa629fe3d9e0ba53368f6438d36/547f20c40ad9f22d/0l6u1h/synthinR_v4.csv", header=TRUE)`.

Comment: Great! I changed the code. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies - the url seems to be temporary. Please revert to the way you had it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `col` argument to `par` sets the *default* plotting colour (i.e. when `col` is not explicitly specified in plotting calls), but unfortunately `col = "black"` is hard-coded into the source of `gaps.plot`.

You can make a modified copy of the function by either (1) viewing the source (<kbd>F2</kbd>  in RStudio, or just executing `gaps.plot`), editing it and assigning it to a new object, or (2) doing something like the following:

```
gaps.plot2 <- eval(parse(text=gsub('col = "black"', 'col = "red"', 
                                   deparse(Synth:::gaps.plot))))
```

and then using `gaps.plot2` as you would use `gaps.plot`:

```
gaps.plot2(synth.res = synth.out34, dataprep.res = dataprep.out34, 
           Ylab = " Log Digital Sales ", Xlab = "Release", Ylim = c(-7, 7) , 
           Main = NA)
```

[image]

Alter the `lwd` similarly. For example to make lines red and have width of 3, use nested `gsub` calls like this:

```
gaps.plot2 <- eval(parse(text=gsub('lwd = 2', 'lwd = 3', 
                                   gsub('col = "black"', 'col = "red"', 
                                        deparse(Synth:::gaps.plot)))))
```